# How to Reset MySQL database with time limit using php

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I have a demo website for the users. It contain database with few tables.
I want to reset the entire database with time frame using PHP.

How can I truncate all the tables every hour?

Comment: you can fire a query for database reset. Or also use cronjob

Comment: could you plz guide me how to do that?

Comment: You write a simple php script that fires a `truncate table` command for each table: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html You call that script on a regular base by executing it as a cron task: `man cron` This is all well documented. You should start reading the documentations available. You starting implementing that script yourself. Then if you run into problems and cannot get your code to work, _then_ is the time to ask a _specific_ question about a _specific_ issue here and add the code you wrote.

Comment: tell me what time frame means, I can show you without cron

Comment: i mean, need to truncate all the tables at a time per every hour.

Comment: Greetings Raja, did you solve this yet? Thx for the email, sorry, I went to sleep. Also, you need to do a "Hey `@Drew` otherwise I would never see these messages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncating every table wouldn't work in this case because some of the tables will contain initial configuration data.

I would set up the basic system exactly as you want it. Then do a one off database dump and a tarball back up of the moodledata directory.

Also create a file in moodledata called `old_climaintenance.html` with a message for users while the site is offline.

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Administration_via_command_line#Offline_mode

Then set up a bash script to go through these steps

1. Rename `old_climaintenance.html` to `climaintenance.html` to let users know its offline.
2. Drop the database
3. Delete the contents of the moodledata directory - except old_climaintenance.html
4. Restore the tarball into moodledata
5. Recreate the database from the data dump
6. Rename `climaintenance.html` to `old_climaintenance.html`

Then set up a cron job to run the bash script every hour.